# Invalid column name 'Length' edited MVC 4 Membership

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to add to the MVC 4 out of the box membership.

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        try
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Mobile);
            //I added model.Mobile
            WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the model

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    // Username and password methods

    public string Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

I also added it to the `UserProfile` Model.  I am getting a SqlException and i just don't see the connection. It seems like such a simple error but. The DB is set to `Nvarchar(MAX)` which is  to try to avoid this error.

```
Invalid column name 'Length'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your comment, seems that you use

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Mobile);
```

if you look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createuserandaccount%28v=vs.111%29.aspx),

```
public static string CreateUserAndAccount(
    string userName,
    string password,
    Object propertyValues,
    bool requireConfirmationToken
)
```

where propertyValues is

> propertyValues
>       Type: System.Object
>       (Optional) A dictionary that contains additional user attributes. The default is null.

so with your usage of the method, model.Mobile is sent as the `propertyValues` parameter, which it's certainly not !

So you should Create your own `CreateUserAndAccount` overload (or a new method) where you could use a *mobile* parameter.

Comment: Althaus I would have to say your right but i don't really understand how to accomplish that. When I read that i feel like i have to put those values into a dictionary and pass the dictionary into the `CreateUserAndAccount` as propertyValues. When i tired that it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually throwing the error because it expects a dictionary of additional properties - try:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new{model.Mobile}, false)
```

This assumes that you have a column called Mobile in the UserProfileTable.  If you wanted to specify a different column name:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new{YourColumnName = model.Mobile}, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is what it's referring to... It appears to be doing a query for a COLUMN NAME called "LENGTH"... which I would suspect is a reserved keyword to determine the Length of a string and causing your error.  Do you have any such column name references of this?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. There is no validation annotations on the model. Can i pass additional values into `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Mobile);` ? Do you have any reccomendations on where i could look for this?

Comment: It breaks right there so I would think it would pull that from the model right?